# How to use this RTP/RTCP library?

Tags: java, rtp, securityexception, rtcp

I`d like to use this library: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/report.html

And I have a question: is it even possible to use it when files in this library have in their package names "java.net..." ? When I tried to compile program in NetBeans i got an exception: "java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.net.RTP.Packets".